# Forwarding of web traffic doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding

I'm trying to make a program that will forward web traffic via dynamic round robin algorithm to one of waiting servers, and send response back. Program should read dynamically changing file with arguments like ip, port, and dynamic weight and based on those reading send information to one of web servers. Second argument in file is web-server ip, and sixth is dynamic weight.

Program looks like this:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
import math
import functools
from operator import itemgetter

settings = list()
weight_list = list()
minus_list = list()

def __getitem__(self, row):
    return self.data[row]

def gcd(L):
    return functools.reduce(math.gcd, L)

def main(setup, error):
    sys.stderr = open(error, 'a')

    for line in open(setup):
        parts = line.split()
        weight_list.append([int(parts[0]), parts[1], int(parts[2]), int(parts[3]), int(parts[4]), int(parts[5])])
    settings = weight_list
    for i in range(len(settings)):
        minus_list.append(settings[i][5])
    minus = gcd(minus_list)
    settings.sort(key=itemgetter(5), reverse=True)
    setting = tuple(settings[0])
    settings[0][5] = settings[0][5]-minus
    threading.Thread(target=server, args=(settings, setup, minus, setting)).start()

def server(settings, setup, minus, *setting):
        try:
                dock_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                print("working")
                dock_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                print("working")
                dock_socket.bind(('', setting[0]))
                print("working")
                dock_socket.listen(5)
                print("working")
                while True:
                        print("working")
                        client_socket = dock_socket.accept()
                        print("not working")
                        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        server_socket.connect((setting[1], setting[2]))
                        threading.Thread(target=forward, args=(client_socket, server_socket)).start()
                        threading.Thread(target=forward, args=(server_socket, client_socket)).start()
        finally:
                if settings[0][5]<=0:
                        weight_list = list()
                        for line in open(setup):
                                parts = line.split()
                                weight_list[line].append((int(parts[0]), parts[1], int(parts[2]), int(parts[3]), int(parts[4]), int(parts[5])))
                        settings = weight_list
                        for i in range(len(settings)):
                                minus_list.append(settings[i][5])
                        minus = gcd(minus_list)
                settings.sort(key=itemgetter(5), reverse=True)
                setting = tuple(settings[0])
                settings[0][5] = settings[0][5]-minus
                threading.Thread(target=server, args=(settings, setup, minus, setting)).start()

def forward(source, destination):
    string = ' '
    while string:
        string = source.recv(4096)
        if string:
            destination.sendall(string)
        else:
            source.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
            destination.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main('round-robin.conf', 'error.log')
```

Program stops right at client_socket = dock_socket.accept()

After that I am trying to connect via  this simple code:

```
import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.connect(('192.168.56.1', 80))
    server_socket.close()
```

And it returns error "connection refused".
I have no idea why, or how to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: Are you on linux? Can you do a netstat -putan | grep 80?

Comment: Yes, I am on linux. Currently port 80 is taken by another app, I temporarily use port 4444. And netstat -putan | grep 4444 returns nothing. Of course i made appropriate changes in code as well. But I am trying to connect from windows.